# Represent buffers like accordion(stack buffers)

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

i don't know how fully describe what exactly plugin do, so i provide screenshot(you can see 2 buffers and them stacked like accordion, 1 behind another or overlayed):
How i can achieve this feature ?

[image: vim screen]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for horizontal "Rolodex mode" (i.e. affecting vertical splits), put the following in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
autocmd VimEnter * set winwidth=999 winminwidth=10
```

The first option maximizes the current window's width; the second shrinks the width of the others to `10`; adapt as you like.

Comment: Looking at the picture, I think there is also a `nowrap` involved

Answer (score 1):

If you want a rolodex where more than one window can be big at a time, you may want to check out a plugin I wrote: https://github.com/mattboehm/vim-accordion. Unfortunately, the size of the shrunk windows is not currently configurable, but I'm happy to make it configurable if you think that would help out.

For what it's worth, I mainly use my plugin when I want to render many levels of a call stack in adjacent splits. (i.e. when A calls B calls C calls D calls E, I like to make my window look like `A | B | C | D | E`). Using accordion, I can move left and right and view any 2 or 3 adjacent windows at a time.

Comment: I saw your plugin and even played with it, but yes, plugin  have not configurable padding for shrunk windows. But if you could provide this functionality with some configurable param would be pretty good and i probably will use it as well. I will monitor your github repo.